# How can I center an ImageView and TextView in a ConstraintLayout while adjusting ImageView size to maintain TextView visibility?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

**Question**

How can I center an ImageView and a TextView within a ConstraintLayout, ensuring that they remain centered regardless of the ConstraintLayout's height, while also ensuring that the ImageView shrinks if necessary to maintain visibility of the TextView?

**Expected results:**

In case of a large ConstraintLayout (centered, but not larger than the original image):

[image: Expected result 1]

In case of a small ConstraintLayout (centered, shrinked image, text still visible):

[image: Expected result 2]

I build the following reproducible example:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/primary_margin"
            android:text="Just a text"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Edit**

The closest solution I have found so far is as follows. However, the only remaining drawback is that I need to manually specify the maximum width and height, whereas my ideal scenario would be to dynamically adjust them according to the image's actual width and height.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_max="200dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_max="200dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/primary_margin"
            android:text="Just a text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take your closest solution, try setting the `ImageView` height and width to `wrap_content` again (so it displays at its native size) but add `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` and `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"`. This basically lets you define the height and width you want (i.e. whatever the image size actually is), but also enforces the constraints, so it acts like `0dp` (i.e. `MATCH_CONSTRAINT`) when necessary:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hi"
        android:textSize="85sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's the same layout in the *Phone* and *Wear OS Square* reference device templates:

[image: The blueprint preview of this layout using the Phone reference template]

[image: The blueprint preview of this layout using the Wear OS Square reference template]

The actual `ImageView` is distorted (because both dimensions are trying to size to `wrap_content`) but the image maintains its aspect ratio to fit in both dimensions (if you're using the default `scaleType`).

[image: The normal layout preview for the Wear OS Square template, showing the image maintaining its aspect ratio]

Comment: I wanted to express my sincere appreciation for your assistance. Your explanation of the solution was incredibly helpful and clear, providing me with the exact information I needed. I'm grateful for your expertise and the effort you put into explaining "what" and "how" it all works. Thank you for your valuable contribution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use packed vertical chaining. You can see more about chains in this video [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PqkWT92BT3U&ab_channel=PhilippLackner). Here is the code snippet how to center image and text.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response and the valuable hint that set me in the right direction. I have successfully implemented the desired functionality using a ConstraintLayout larger than the image. However, I encountered an issue when I tried setting the ConstraintLayout to a smaller size, specifically 100dpx100dp. In this scenario, the text within the ImageView gets partially hidden as it doesn't fit properly. Is there a way to make the ImageView shrink accordingly in such cases? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.